# Error handling in Javascript promises(throwing errors)

Tags: javascript, exception, es6-promise

I would like to do some error handling on the response received from a call I am making and then move to the catch if the specific null check is hit. Something like this:

```
    fetch('example.json')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data === null) {
                //go to catch
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("error happened", error);
        })
```

What would be the best way to go about doing something like this? Any red flags with throwing an error inside a then block?

Comment: if (response.data === null) { throw "Your error" }

Comment: You can wrap this function inside a promise and reject it if your condition is not satisfied.

Comment: im wondering also about the code practices too - is it weird to throw an error in a then block, it feels like i am throwing an axe into my foot so that i could use my medical insurance - i was hoping there was a way to check this response object without having to trigger the 'extreme' measure of throwing an exception. for example, 'continue' in a loop would gently move you to the next cycle, as opposed to doing 'break' and then writing another for loop. I am hoping for a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: @berlin - Re not having to trigger the 'extreme' measure of throwing an exception, I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64536336/157247) to give you an alternative. It has effectively the same outcome. (`throw` isn't really extreme in JavaScript, though.)

Comment: agreed - feels like javascript errors are much less significant than say, an error in java. was still hoping there'd be a chance for me to get by without explicitly throwing one

Comment: @berlin - The big difference in this between Java and JavaScript is that in Java, you can only use `throw` with `Throwable`s (`Error`s and `Exception`s), but in JavaScript, you can `throw` any value -- a string, a number, a non-`Error` object, anything. So if you don't need stack information, you can throw a string or something rather than an `Error` (it's the `Error` object that captures the stack information) if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `throw` in a promise handler, that rejects the promise the handler returns. So:

```
fetch('example.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.data === null) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("error happened", error);
    })
```

What you throw will be the rejection reason the `catch` handler sees. It doesn't *have* to be an `Error`, but as with synchronous code, it's generally best if it is.

**But**, note that A) A `fetch` `response` doesn't have a `data` property, and B) You need to check for HTTP success and parse the JSON that was returned.

You probably want something like this:

```
fetch('example.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            // (I tend to use an specialized `Error` type here
            // More on my anemic blog:
            // http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data === null) {
            throw new Error("The data is null");
        })
        // ...do something with `data`...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("error happened", error);
    });
```

---

In a comment on the question you've said:

> i was hoping there was a way to check this response object without having to trigger the 'extreme' measure of throwing an exception

You do have an alternative which is basically identical in outcome: Return a rejected promise. Here's my second code block above adapted to do that:

```
fetch('example.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            // (I tend to use an specialized `Error` type here
            // More on my anemic blog:
            // http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)
            return Promise.reject(new Error("HTTP error " + response.status));
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data === null) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("The data is null"));
        })
        // ...do something with `data`...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("error happened", error);
    });
```

And as with the `throw` version, you don't *have* to use an `Error`, it's just best practice. It can be anything you want.

Comment: great - thanks for the edit, i was hoping i could do something like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can throw an `Error` object from within your promise handler.

```
fetch('example.json')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.data === null) {
      throw new Error('oopsie');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("error happened", error); // will show "Error: oopsie"
  })
```